# Why do linear differential operators with constant coefficients behave like polynomials?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $D$ be the differential operator in $Hom(C^\infty(R), C^\infty(R))$. Is it a coincidence, for example, that $x^2 - 2x + 1 = (x-1)(x-1)$ for all real x and that 
\begin{alignat}{1}
(D^2-2D+1)(f) &= D(Df) - 2Df + f &= D(Df - f)-(Df - f)
\\
&= (D-1)(Df - f) &= (D-1)((D-1)(f)) 
\\
&= ((D-1)(D-1))(f) &?
\end{alignat}

Comment: Your post is desperately in need of some [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please use it.

Comment: $D$ commutes with itself - that's all.

Comment: The equality holds in any ring, and the linear operations form a ring (with composition as multiplication) more or less by definition

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you. But then how would we include coefficients that are not integers (if D is the identity and we only allow addition and multiplication)?

Comment: You don't, for the given reason. Non-constant coefficients do not commute with differentiation operators (in the same variable). Or if you do, you operate then in a non-commutative ring and have to be careful to apply the correct commutators, like $Dx=xD+1$.

Comment: Math is all about structure I guess

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That really deserves to be an answer instead of a comment, however brief.